# LibGDX Box2D Tiled map artifacts

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, artifacts, tiled

I have a problem with rendering tiled map in LibGDX. When I move the camera appear artifacts.

This is my tileset with margin and spacing (fragment):
[tileset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwlG9.png)

When I move the camera appear artifacts:
[artifacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMYYp.png)

And here is my rendering world class.

```
private GameApp game;

private OrthographicCamera gameCamera;
private Viewport viewport;

private TiledMap map;
private TmxMapLoader mapLoader;
private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer mapRenderer;

private MainCharacter character;

private World world;
private Box2DDebugRenderer worldRenderer;

public GameplayScreen(GameApp game) {
    this.game = game;

    gameCamera = new OrthographicCamera();

    viewport = new FitViewport(
            game.getDisplayWidth() / GameApp.PPM,
            game.getDisplayHeight() / GameApp.PPM,
            gameCamera
        );

    mapLoader = new TmxMapLoader();
    map = mapLoader.load("testmap1.tmx");
    mapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map, 1 / GameApp.PPM);

    gameCamera.position.set(new Vector2(600 / GameApp.PPM, 200 / GameApp.PPM), 0);
    gameCamera.zoom -= 0.5;

    world = new World(new Vector2(0, -10), true);
    worldRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();

    BodyDef bDef = new BodyDef();
    PolygonShape shape = new PolygonShape();
    FixtureDef fDef = new FixtureDef();
    Body body;

    for (MapObject mapObject : map.getLayers().get("obstacles").getObjects().getByType(RectangleMapObject.class)) {
        Rectangle rectangle = ((RectangleMapObject) mapObject).getRectangle();

        bDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.StaticBody;
        bDef.position.set(
                (rectangle.getX() + rectangle.getWidth() / 2) / GameApp.PPM, 
                (rectangle.getY() + rectangle.getHeight() / 2) / GameApp.PPM
        );

        body = world.createBody(bDef);

        shape.setAsBox(rectangle.getWidth() / 2 / GameApp.PPM, rectangle.getHeight() / 2 / GameApp.PPM);
        fDef.shape = shape;

        body.createFixture(fDef);
    }

    character = new MainCharacter(world);
}

@Override
public void show() {

}

public void handleInput(float delta) {
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.UP)) {
        character.getBody().applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, 3.8f), character.getBody().getWorldCenter(), true);
    }

    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT) && character.getBody().getLinearVelocity().x <= 1) {
        character.getBody().applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0.05f, 0), character.getBody().getWorldCenter(), true);
    }

    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT) && character.getBody().getLinearVelocity().x >= -1) {
        character.getBody().applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(-0.05f, 0), character.getBody().getWorldCenter(), true);
    }
}

public void update(float delta) {
    handleInput(delta);

    world.step(1/60f, 6, 2);

    gameCamera.position.x = character.getBody().getPosition().x;
    gameCamera.position.y = character.getBody().getPosition().y;

    gameCamera.update();
    mapRenderer.setView(gameCamera);
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    update(delta);

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    mapRenderer.render();
    worldRenderer.render(world, gameCamera.combined);
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    viewport.update(width, height);
}

...
```

I read that the spacing in the tileset help. But it still does not work properly.

---

EDIT:

```
TmxMapLoader.Parameters par = new TmxMapLoader.Parameters();
  par.textureMinFilter = TextureFilter.Nearest;
  par.textureMagFilter = TextureFilter.Nearest;

map = mapLoader.load("testmap1.tmx", par);
```

I edit my code, but still not work. Seeking solutions for a few days.

---

EDIT2

I try again. Code:

```
atlasMapLoader = new AtlasTmxMapLoader();
testMap = atlasMapLoader.load("testmap1.tmx");
```

This load my map. I have ".txt" file:

[image]

In Tiled Editor I add property to a map called "atlas" value "TilesetBig.txt".

Now, the map does not display tiles. Obstacles with box2d are still visible. What can I do wrong?

---

Finally i used OrthoCachedTiledMapRendered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pack your tileset with **Nearest** texture filter being set.

If you are using **Linear** one the GL is averaging border pixels using surrounding one what causes glitches like this.

[Read this article](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=1403) to get more information about texture filters in LibGDX.

Comment: Thank you. I edit my question. I try to use Nearest filter, but it still does not work.

Comment: Have you used "reduce border artifact" in Texture Packer also?

Comment: I do not use texture packer. I have prepared a graphic with spaces between tiles in Gimp. I understand that I have to use it?

Comment: Yup you should definitely use TexturePacker - it is far more convenient than making it manually :) Free version should be enough for your purposes. I suppose that in your prepared graphic there are some almost-transparent artifacts on borders and they cause issues

Comment: Its easy, Gimp have a plugin for that :). Ok, I try this solutions. But I have a big picture of the tiles, so I put it to the texture packer and he will create for me a ready graphics (with spaces) and a data file?

Comment: you need only graphic file that you will load into TIled - in TP set option not to trim graphics

Comment: I can not find any example of using class of AtlasTmxMapLoader. I have files "testuretest.pack" and "texuretest.png" and a map file. Do you know any article on this subject?